# Robot Localization pkg / Motion Model prediction step

Tags: ros2, robot-localization, ekf, orientation

As I was investigating the transition functions in the prediction step in the ROS Robot Localization pkg (ekf.cpp)  .

I found for the orientation equations there are as follows:

- Roll angle is the result of the first row from the multiplication of (Rz*Ry*Rx) 3D rot matrix by the (Imu_angular_rates * delta_time) , then all the result is divided by cos(pitch) to obtain the desired predicted Roll angle.
- Pitch angle is normally , the direct result of the second row from the multiplication of (Rz*Ry*Rx) 3D rot matrix by the (Imu angular rates * delta_time) .
- Yaw angle is the result of the third row form the multiplication of only (Rz * Rx) by the (Imu_angular_rates * delta_time), then the result is divided also by cos (pitch) to obtain the final predicted Yaw angle.

My questions are:

1- Why for roll and yaw angles , the result is divided by cos(pitch) ?

2- Why the yaw angle is determined from only the rotations (Rz * Rx) and Ry is excluded ?

Do these manipulations are carried on to just avoid singularities and the "Gimbal lock"  effect than can arise from 3D rotation of Euler angles (As in this pkg Quaternion are not used), or there any other considerations are made here for this internal motion model ?

Comment: Can you point to specific lines in the code base? I recommend going to the file in GitHub and pressing 'y' to get a permalink.